# Adding letter to every word in variable(string)

Tags: php, regex, append

I got variable

```
$test = "test1<br />
         test2<br />
         test3";
```

I want to add before every word in the string a Letter.Also the string contains break tags as i post it.

Want to look like:

```
$test = "Ptest1<br />
         Ptest2<br />
         Ptest3";
```

Comment: i tried preg_replace('^(\h*[A-Za-z])','P$1',$arr); but i failed to set the preg_replace pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex to loop through the string and add your value.

```
$arr = "test1<br />
         test2<br />
         test3";
echo preg_replace('/^(\h*)([A-Za-z])/m','$1P$2',$arr);
```

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/630398
Regex Demo: https://regex101.com/r/xV9nY0/1

The `/`s are delimiters telling where the regex starts and ends. 
 The `m` modifier makes the `^` match at the start of each line.
The `\h*` is any amount of whitespace before an alpha character (you can add to that character class if other characters should also be allowed).

To allow the line to start with numbers as well try:

```
echo preg_replace('/^(\h*)([A-Za-z\d])/m','$1P$2',$arr);
```

Comment: and if i add for example 05/2016 its not adding anything

Comment: add `\d` to the character class, then the next line can start with a number as well.

Comment: when i  tried it in the eval.in its working but in my code it only adds P to the first line

Comment: Yes.Its the same as yours

Comment: Umm well that's going to be hard to diagnose. Does it work here, https://3v4l.org/?

Comment: Ok its working there too.Lets try another thing,If i replace <br /> with \n how can i do the same thing before every word (delimiter will be whitespace)

Comment: This answer doesn't care about `<br />` it is looking for new lines. At every newline it adds a `P` after the any whitespace and before the alphanumerical character.

Comment: Yes,but if i swap br with \n it will not add new line

Comment: @SebastianJeliazkov In your actual code are there line breaks after the `<br />`s?

Comment: Yes there are.But if i swap <br> with \n there will no be line breaks and i need regex to add P to every word the separator will be whitespace.

Comment: Provide an exact example of what you have. Is it https://eval.in/630421, https://eval.in/630422, or https://eval.in/630423

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = "test1<br />
         test2<br />
         test3";

$temp_test = [];

$char = 'P';

$data = explode('<br />', $test);

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $temp_test[] = $char.''.trim($value);
}

$new_test = implode('<br />', $temp_test);
```

Comment: Its adding some whitespaces after P i dont know why

Comment: It's because of new lines. Try the above trimming the whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

One-line solution using `preg_replace` function and a specific regexp pattern:

```
$letter = "P";
$replaced = preg_replace("/(?<=[^<]|^)\b(\w+?)\b/", $letter. "$1", $test);
```

[DEMO link](https://eval.in/630401)